# Rails4 formから別画面へ遷移して選択する

Tags: ruby-on-rails

入力画面で選択項目で、ブランドを選択する項目を実装中です。

「ブランド選択する」ボタンを押すとbrand_selectページへ飛び対象のブランドをクリックすると再び入力画面へ戻り、ブランドが選択されているように作りたいです。

- brand_selectページへはどのようにしたら飛べるでしょうか。現在はvalidateに阻まれて遷移すらできません。
- 対象のブランドをクリックしたらフォームへ自動で戻り、ブランドが選択されている状態にするにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

ページを切り替えるまでもない実装はJavascriptで実装するのも手だと思います。

現在作成中のフォーム画面とブランド選択画面をフォーム画面に統合し、ブランドを選択するボタンが押された時に、フォームを非表示にし、隠してあったブランド選択UIを表示して、あたかもページが切り替わっているように見せるのはどうでしょうか。

```
<div class='main_form'>
  ここにフォーム
  <button class='brand_button'>ブランドを選択する</button>
</div>

<div class='brand_select'>
  ここにブランド選択のUIを作成
</div>

<script>
  $(function(){

    // ブランドを選択するボタンが押されたら
    $('.brand_button').on('click',function(){

      // コンテンツの表示を切り替える
      $('.main_form').hide()
      $('.brand_select').show()
    });

  });
</script>

<style>
  // ブランド選択画面を隠しておく
  .brand_select {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: 私もこの実装(表示の切替)の方が好ましいと思います。行って帰ってくる間に、何かしらの事故でサーバーからエラー応答があったりすると嫌なので。